# Number of geocoded points in concentric circles in R

Tags: r, geocoding, arcgis, euclidean-distance

I have a data set of around 36K hotels geocoded with latitude and longitude.

For each of them, I would need to know how many other hotels (and also which of the others) are placed in different concentric circles around each point ( 2miles, 5miles, 10miles).

For example, the dataset looks like this:

```
ID Latitude Longitude Rooms
1      N       K       200
2      N       K       150
3      N       K        80
4      N       K       140
5      N       K       100
```

I would need a measure of density for each hotel in each concentric circle (which is normally calculated by dividing the number of room of the focal hotel per hotel by the total number of rooms in its concentric circle)

Normally, I would calculate the distance between each point and then filter for the ones that are within each distance but with 36k points, it would take a lot of time because I would go to calculate the distance among each point when I probably need the distance for each point with other 4-5 others maximum.

Do you have an idea on how to calculate the distance and then the density efficiently using R or ArcGIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the best way to make your code more efficient is not by getting a more efficient distance calculating algorithm, but by only applying that algorithm to a couple of hotels.

You could do a rough "square" approximation very quickly:

1. make a new dataset of hotels sorted by latitude
2. make a new dataset of hotels sorted by longitude

For each hotel:

3. make 2 new empty lists: `hotels_in_lat_range` and `hotels_in_long_range`
4. start at your hotel in the latitude-sorted dataset, and go up until you reach a certain limit
5. go back down until you reach a lower limit, adding the hotels to `hotels_in_lat_range` as you go along
6. repeat steps 4 and 5 for the longitude-sorted dataset, adding hotels to `hotels_in_long_range`
7. for every hotel that is in both lists, calculate the distance between your test hotel and that hotel. If the distance is less than your circle radius, include it when you calculate the density.

For the upper and lower limits of latitude and longitude, I'd recommend using the following approximation (I wrote this in Python because I don't know R):

```
min_lat = max(-89.9, test_lat - 4 * math.degrees(test_rad/Earth_rad))
max_lat = min(89.9, test_lat + 4 * math.degrees(test_rad/Earth_rad))
min_long = max(
    -180.0, 
    test_lat - 4 * math.degrees(
        test_rad/(Earth_rad * min(cos(min_lat), cos(max_lat)))
    )
)
max_long = min(
    180.0,
    test_lat + 4 * math.degrees(
        test_rad/(Earth_rad * min(cos(min_lat), cos(max_lat)))
    )
)
```

This is a reasonable approximation when your testing radius is significantly smaller than the Earth's radius. I'd recommend staying within 100 miles.